# Finding list menu elements in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple horizontal list menu with the ul li items containing a further ul (which I have styled to be display:none;

I am however, having trouble using the .slideUp() function to make the child ul elements to display when the mouse hovers over the parent li item.

See the jQuery and HTML code I have written so far respectively!

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

              $('#h li').hover(
                function () {
                    //show its submenu
                    $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
                },
                function () {
                    //hide its submenu
                     $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
                }
            );
        }
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id= "nav">
        <ul id="h">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item F</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu C</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu D</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu E</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Oh and the CSS just incase it's a problem with that :D

```
#nav {
text-align:center;
float:left;
width:1000px;
}

#nav ul {
list-style:none;
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#nav ul li {
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}

#nav ul li a {
    background-image: url(../images/menu_sprite.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
text-decoration:none;
width:121px;
height:31px;
padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -35px;
}

#nav ul li ul {
list-style:none;
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code as you have it, and it worked the way I "expected" it to work (ran it on its own, so didn't have to do brian_d's syntax fix). The jquery you have is correct, and does what I think you think you want it to do. Can you explain in more detail what it's doing "wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

              $('#h a').hover(
                function () {
                    //show its submenu
                    $(this).next('ul').slideDown(100);
                },
                function () {
                    //hide its submenu
                     $(this).next('ul').slideUp(100);
                }
            );
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your closing parenthesis `);`

ie) You have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
}
```

but need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#h').find('li.someclass').each(function(){
          $(this).hover(function(){
              $(this).find("ul").show();    
          }, function(){
              $(this).find("ul").hide();
          });
      });
    }
```

Comment: And put "someclass" on LI of first level.